# Can't get response from the website, postal-code.co.uk

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrapy results after inputing keywords in this website https://postal-code.co.uk/, but was directed to another website with only "restricted", by using the link with keywords: https://postal-code.co.uk/ajax/search.php?word=Edward+Avenue,+Camberley,+Surrey,+GU15&geocodeProvider=1, I have tried to add a referer in its header, when using the command:
scrapy.http.Request(url='https://postal-code.co.uk/ajax/search.php?word=Edward+Avenue%2C+Camberley%2C+Surrey%2C+GU15&geocodeProvider=1',headers={'Referer':'https://postal-code.co.uk/'})
but still can't resolve it, please help.... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The website loads the search results using ajax. It also checks the headers and cookies being sent with the request. See a sample `scrapy` spider where I have sent the specific headers required. Scrapy will handle the cookies automatically.

```py
import scrapy

class PostalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'postal'
    allowed_domains = ['postal-code.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://postal-code.co.uk']

    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'referer': 'https://postal-code.co.uk/',
            'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36',
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }
        yield response.follow("https://postal-code.co.uk/ajax/search.php?word=Edward+Avenue,+Camberley,+Surrey,+GU15&geocodeProvider=1", 
            callback=self.parse_results, headers=headers)

    def parse_results(self, response):
        for result in response.json():
            yield result
```

Sample screenshot of the spider run
[image: Spider run sample]